# ActiveRecord having 2 FKs from the same column in a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi I want to allow my users to message each other and I thought of having a table structure like

User:
ID | Name

Message:
To | From | Body

I'm relatively new to rails and I'm not sure what my model should look like or how to build the relation where I have two FKs from the same column. To & From are the user who sent the message and the receiver. I'm using ActiveRecord for my models.

Can anyone get me pointed in the right direction here? I have a feeling I should be using have_many through but I would like to have the relationship has exactly 2.

Comment: Did my answer worked for you?

Comment: I'm not sure yet I can't test it when I created the form to create a message a lot of my unit tests failed and I get the message First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty. I'm trying to figure this out at the moment

Comment: Ok.Dont forget to accept later when it helped you :)

Comment: No problem I'll do it as soon as I know it works

Comment: In which folder is your `users_controller.rb` file is placed.

Comment: its in the Controllers folder, the same as the messages_controller.rb file

Comment: One advice.As it is different problem,posting it as a different question will make more attention and you may get the solution too.

Comment: Better you edit this question to its previous state.There are chances of getting duplicate flag to the new question which you posted.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53900/discussion-between-pavan-and-jeff-finn)

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
#user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :messages

end

#message.rb
Class Message < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :sender,class_name => "User",foreign_key => 'from'

belongs_to :receiver,class_name => "User",foreign_key => 'to'

end
```

**Note:** It is preferable and also recommended to have `integer foreign_keys`.If you would like to change the `foreign_keys`,i would recommend the names `sender_id` and `receiver_id`.

Comment: I was testing my models in the console, Message is the only model that can't be accessed. It throws NameError: undefined local variable or method `class_name' for #<Class:0x007fbfbc11af48> if I remove the 2 belongs_to relationships