# Rails Unitialized Constant in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

This is a follow up question to [ActiveRecord having 2 FKs from the same column in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23714766/activerecord-having-2-fks-from-the-same-column-in-a-table?noredirect=1#comment36458150_23714766) I am getting the message 'uninitialized constant User::Message' and I don't know what is causing it.

My create action from my Message controller is

```
def create
@message = current_user.packages.build(message_params)
@message.sender = current_user
@message.receiver = User.find(params[:id])
@message.date = Time.now
if @message.save
  flash[:success] = "Message Created!"
else
  flash[:danger] = "Message Not Created!"
end

 redirect_to user_path
end
```

I added the controller to my routes.rb file

```
resources :messages, only: [:create, :destroy]
```

My action from my User controller is

```
def show
@user = User.find(params[:id])

@message = @user.messages.build #error is thrown here

@package_feed_items = @user.packages.paginate(page: params[:page],:per_page => 5)
@route_feed_items = @user.routes.paginate(page: params[:page],:per_page => 5)
end
```

The form is in a partial in my 'messages' folder from the views directory. This is called from a view in my users controller with

```
<%= render 'messages/create_message_modal' %>
```

my Message model is now

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sender, class_name => :user, foreign_key => 'sender_id'
  belongs_to :receiver, class_name => :user, foreign_key => 'receiver_id'

  default_scope -> { order('created_at DESC') }

  validates :receiver_id, presence: true
  validates :sender_id, presence: true
  validates :body, presence: true
  validates :date, presence: true

  state_machine :initial => :unOpened do
   state :unOpened, value: "Un-Opened"
   state :opened, value: "Opened"
   state :deleted, value: "Deleted"

   event :open do
     transition :unOpened => :opened
   end

   event :delete do
     transition :opened => :deleted
   end
 end
end
```

and my user model is

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    ... other relations ... 
    has_many :messages
    ... validation & state machine ...
end
```

EDIT
The tail of my log file

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 8ms

NameError (uninitialized constant User::Message):app/controllers/users_controller.rb:33:in `show'


  Rendered /Users/jeff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered /Users/jeff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (0.7ms)
  Rendered /Users/jeff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered /Users/jeff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (11.2ms)
```

Comment: do you mind to show us the errors log?

Comment: Please post your message model as well. Are both models under app/models? What are their filenames?

Comment: I've just posted the complete model. All my models are under the app/models folder they are called message.rb and user.rb

Answer (score 0):

Specify the class_name option to user model like below,

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages, class_name: 'Message'
end
```

Try this it should work, anyway you need to find why the direct relation is not working.

Comment: unfortunately this didn't fix the problem. Thanks for the suggestion tho